# Swift2.0 、Facebookと他のアプリと連動（ランキングについて）

Tags: xcode, swift2

今現在得点を競うゲームを開発中なのですが、ランキング機能を実装したいと思っています。
他のアプリで良く見かていて、実装したいのが、「Facebookに連動して友達と点数を競いランキングで表示」です。
点数を比較してランキング表示をするというのは公式等ににサンプルはあるのでしょうか？
それとも全て自作で考える必要があるのでしょうか？

回答よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

『公式』と言うのが何を指しているのかよくわかりませんが、少なくとも、Appleが用意しているサンプルコードの中には、言われるようなものは無いと思います。

ParseやNifty Cloud Mobile Backendなどの、Facebookと連携するところまでやってくれるmBaaSを使って、実装するのが良いのでは無いでしょうか？
（Parseはもうすぐ終了しますが・・・）

Facebookと連携する部分を自力でやるのであれば、Game Kitの機能にあるGKLeaderboardsを使うのが楽かと思われます。

Comment: 詳しい回答ありがとうございます。とても参考になりました。